# Bot Framework Language Translation

Tags: botframework

The first version of the Bot Framework advertised automatic language translation as a major Bot Connector feature as outlined in the [v1 Bot Framework Overview page](http://docs-v1.botframework.com/).

However, the v3 documentation doesn't mention it. I was wondering if this feature is no longer available or should we use the Cognitive Services Text APIs instead?

Here's what I tried with a Skype Bot:

1. I would like to speak in German
2. May I speak in French
3. fr-FR

Everything I've tried hasn't worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is something which I've looked into while building my own bot as well. The feature is no longer available in V3 and will have to call the Translator API directly. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/1156

Answer (score 0):

In V4, you can use the code as below

```
  Resources.Global.Culture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```